# How should I set a timer which executes slow function in endless loop? (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

In the console application, I have written a function which takes 1-2 seconds to execute and then prints something on console. This function is run in endless loop.

After switching to Winforms, the function now generates an output which is then printed to the form graphically.

In order for the form to actually refresh, I cannot use endless loop in WinForms - I use a timer which calls the function on each tick (The "code logic" variables are in sync with the output).

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //tick time = 10
    {
        output = ModifyOutput(); //takes about 1-2 secs
        Draw(output); //changes the form
    }
```

Questions:

1. My timer currently has 0.01 seconds tick rate. Does it mean that after the function ends, it is called again in 0.01 seconds? Or is it called 100 times a second?
2. How can I modify the timer to call the function in exact times, e.g every 3 seconds (let's say I have an upper bound for the maximal execution time) ?

Comment: #1 is super trivial to answer yourself by debugging, no?

Comment: I'm not really sure with the debugging.. the function will not run in parallel, maybe they are queued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer executes every interval that it is set at, meaning the logic that the timer executes will repeat with a delay of the interval.

To sync the timer execution, you want to record the time at which the timer executes and then then have a condition within the timer execution that it must be a factor off the last time it ran in order for it to continue:

```
private long _lastTimeRan = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //tick time = 10
{
    var now = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    //if the last time ran is less than 3 seconds ago, skip the timer tick.
    if(_lastTimeRan > (now - 30_000_000)) {
        return;
    }

    _lastTimeRan = now;
    //execute logic.
}
```

Comment: I added a refresh function `return; }  _lastTimeRan = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks; //execute logic` and it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: If this solution has answered the question, can you please mark it as such.

Comment: If you fix the code so it updates the _lastTimeRan :)